# How to integrate coinbase api into my website..?

Tags: php, bitcoin

As per my understanding coin-base API providing me such functionality like fetch buy/sell bit coin prices also they all allow to buy/sell bitcoins. so that's I want to integrate that API into my panel.

So for that one I have created my account to their website and also add My-app successfully and they providing me two first one is api key and other one is api secret key.

I have go through their document but didn't get exact idea for next step.

Any one have idea after that how may I used that key and get live buy/sell bit-coin prices or buy/sell bit-coin...?

Answer (score 2):

To get the buy/sell price of bitcoin based on the Coinbase exchange, you don't need any API keys.

Simply send a request to their open REST API and display the result.

**PHP Example:**

```
$url = "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$price = $json["amount"];
echo $price;
```

**Javascript/XML Example:**

```
<html>
<div id="btc"></div>
<script>
        var xbtc = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xbtc.open('GET', 'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/book', true);
        xbtc.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xbtc.readyState == 4){
        var ticker = JSON.parse(xbtc.responseText);
        var price = ticker.bids[0][0];
        document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "$" + price;
        }
        };
        xbtc.send();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok but If i want to sent request for buy/sell then what to do is their any way...?

Comment: If you actually want to buy and sell through the api, you will need to use your api keys. I'very done it with bitfinex, any exchange api will work, I haven't tried coinbase's but it should be described in their documentation.

Comment: Ok can you just let me know the bitfinex will provide live bitcoin buy/sell prices and also we buy/sell bitcoin using bitfinex api..?

Comment: @Codebrekers did you find any solution for the Selling api for coinbase? i am also encountering the same issue